# MongoDB 3.4 - Is it possible to perform join from more than 2 collections using either `$graphlookup` or something else?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to join (using $graphlookup or any other approach) more than 2 collections ? 
e.g. I have 3 collections:

**users**, **usergroups**, **queues** with below relationship:

`user` has one or many `queues`

`user` has one or many `usergroups`

`usergroup` has one or many `queues`

now for a given `user`, I want all the `queue` documents (either directly associated, or via user groups association)

**Update**
This query worked for me:

```
{
  "aggregate": "user",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$match": {
        "name": "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "$graphLookup": {
        "from": "queue",
        "startWith": "$queues",
        "connectFromField": "queues",
        "connectToField": "name",
        "as": "userqueues"
      }
    },
    {
      "$graphLookup": {
        "from": "usergroup",
        "startWith": "$userGroups",
        "connectFromField": "userGroups",
        "connectToField": "name",
        "as": "allusergroups"
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": "$allusergroups"
    },
    {
      "$graphLookup": {
        "from": "queue",
        "startWith": "$allusergroups.queues",
        "connectFromField": "allusergroups",
        "connectToField": "name",
        "as": "groupqueues"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this aggregate pipeline a shot.

```js
// Run this on user

[{
    $lookup: {
      "from": "queus",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user",
      "as": "user_queus"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {

      "from": "usergroup",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "users",
      "as": "usergroups"

    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "usergroups"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "queus",
      "localField": "usergroups._id",
      "foreignField": "usergroup",
      "as": "usergroup_queus"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The suggested pipeline worked. posting the actual aggregation query I ended up creating for reference in my quesion.

Comment: Awesome!! Happy to help